# Autofilling VLOOKUP down a column in a 33 sheet google docs workbook changing only the sheet reference

Tags: autofill, google-sheets-api

How do I autofill a vlookup formula in a google sheet down a column so it only changes the sheet lookup reference in a 33 sheet book? In row four I have the following VLOOKUP formulas in columns A-F and would like to autofill down only changing the sheet reference for each row.

```
='1'!D2
='1'!E2
='1'!G2
='1'!H47
='1'!G49
=SUM('1'!B8,'1'!B14,'1'!B20,'1'!B26,'1'!B32,'1'!B38,'1'!B44)
```

Help please.

Comment: Try using the [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) which was described in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/_aLhavFGWv0) as a way to auto-populate cells.

Comment: That still changed the cell number reference and not the sheet number. Thanks though.